# Yii2 migration transaction methods, safeup() and safedown() not working

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I am using the safeUp and safeDown methods for Database transactions in yii but it seems not to be working. Here is my code below:

```
    public function safeUp()
{
    $this->createTable(self::TABLE_EMPLOYMENT_HISTORY, [
        'id' => $this->integer() . ' UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY',
        'user_id' => $this->integer()->unsigned()->notNull(),
        'start_date' => $this->dateTime()->notNull(),
        'end_date' => $this->dateTime(),
        'role' => $this->string(150)->notNull(),
        'position' => $this->string(50)->notNull(),
        'achievements' => $this->text(),
        'created_at' => $this->dateTime()->notNull(),
        'updated_at' => $this->dateTime()->notNull(),
        'status' => $this->string(50)->notNull()
    ]);
    $this->addForeignKey('fk_' . self::TABLE_EMPLOYMENT_HISTORY . '_' . self::TABLE_USERS . '_id', self::TABLE_EMPLOYMENT_HISTORY, 'user_id', self::TABLE_USERS, 'id');
    $this->addForeignKey('fk_' . self::TABLE_EMPLOYMENT_HISTORY . '_' . self::TABLE_STATUSES . '_key', self::TABLE_MISTAKE, 'status', self::TABLE_STATUSES, 'key');
}

public function safeDown()
{
    $this->dropForeignKey('fk_' . self::TABLE_EMPLOYMENT_HISTORY . '_' . self::TABLE_STATUSES . '_key', self::TABLE_EMPLOYMENT_HISTORY);
    $this->dropForeignKey('fk_' . self::TABLE_EMPLOYMENT_HISTORY . '_' . self::TABLE_USERS . '_id', self::TABLE_EMPLOYMENT_HISTORY);
    $this->dropTable(self::TABLE_EMPLOYMENT_HISTORY);

}
```

When I ran that, It said of course that the table `TABLE_MISTAKE` does not exist when trying to create the foreign key. I was expecting a rollback  but that did not happen, instead, it went ahead to create the table 'EMPLOYMENT_HISTORY'.

Why is it creating the table despite using the safeup method?

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is a chance that your db does not support transactions for creating tables. As far as I know MySql does not. So your code triggers a rollback but MySql itself is not able to roll the table creation back, because it does not support this.

Comment: Okay thanks @chris---

Comment: Hi @chris--- I came across this now http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html. waiting for your reply.

Comment: So what? Look further: [such as those that create or drop databases, those that create, drop, or alter tables or stored routines](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cannot-roll-back.html)

Comment: Oh my bad. Thanks chris---

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cannot-roll-back.html):

> Some statements cannot be rolled back. In general, these include data
>   definition language (DDL) statements, such as those that create or
>   drop databases, those that create, drop, or alter tables or stored
>   routines.
>
> You should design your transactions not to include such statements. If
>   you issue a statement early in a transaction that cannot be rolled
>   back, and then another statement later fails, the full effect of the
>   transaction cannot be rolled back in such cases by issuing a
>   `ROLLBACK` statement.

So it's normal behavior. PostgreSQL for example doesn't have this problem.